# counts observations in a month keeping daily rows

Tags: sql, proc-sql

let's say I have this data:

```
data Have;
input ID callDate :ddmmyy. ;
format callDate ddmmyy10.;
datalines4;
001 30/11/2020 
002 30/11/2020 
003 30/11/2020 
004 30/11/2020
005 30/11/2020
002 01/12/2020
004 02/12/2020 
;;;;
run;
```

Basically what I  will be getting is another table grouped by day, right? So I want that on all days that belong to a month, the variable "monthcount" counts all IDs in that month. The outcome would be like this:

```
data want;
input callDate :ddmmyy. monthcount;
format callDate ddmmyy10.;
datalines4;
30/11/2020 5 
01/12/2020 2
02/12/2020 2
;;;;
run;
```

As you can see, for december the count is 2 on both rows because the december total is 2.
I want to keep the day grouping, but the "monthcount" would, well, count by month.
Is there a way to do this in `proc sql`?

How would it change if I wanted to count the distinct ID's in a month, so same thing but instead of being ALL those in a month, just the unique ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select d.date,
       (select count(*)
        from t t2
        where intnx('DTMONTH', d.date, 0) = intnx('DTMONTH', t2.date) and
              intnx('DTYEAR', d.date, 0) = intnx('DTYEAR', t2.date)
       ) as month_count
from (select distinct date from t) d
```

Comment: It's giving me an error on "month_count", it says expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, etc.

Comment: @amestrian . . . There was a dangling `and` in the `where` clause.